# Not able to import jsx file from the directory, react

Tags: reactjs

Right now bar chart is being displayed by the App.js file, but I want to shift that whole code to Mismatch.jsx file and access it in App.js 's return

I am not able to import mismatch.jsx file to my app.js file
it is giving me following error

```
ModuleNotFoundError
Could not find module in path: './src/components' relative to '/src/index.js'
```

https://codesandbox.io/s/react-chartjs-2-5bsbr?file=/src/index.js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change it to following

```
import  Mismatch  from "./container/mismatchdata/mismatch";
```

Also install bootstrap

Comment: Thanks that works, also could you pls suggest how do i shift the bar chart code to mismatch.jsx

Comment: I have updated please check https://codesandbox.io/s/react-chartjs-2-p9zdo?file=/src/index.js